# Codeigniter Form Validation run Always returns FALSE

Tags: php, codeigniter

I modified a little bit code from some user registration tutorial and I don't know why it doesn't work. Before modification, it worked. I just add few records to table in database and form.

This is a function in controller in which '$this->form_validation->run() == FALSE' always return FALSE
If i delete form_validation and if/else statement it add records to database, but if form_validation is present it always go to $this->index

**Fragment of controller Users**

```
public function registration()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'UserName','required|min_length[5]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email','required|min_length[5]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','required|min_length[5]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('con_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'firstname','required|min_length[5]'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'lastname','required|min_length[5]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('adress', 'adress','required|min_length[5]');


    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
    $this->index();


    }
    else
    {
        $this->user_model->add_user();
        redirect("users/index");
    }

}
```

This is my **view file**

```
<div class="registration">



<h1>Registration</h1>
 <?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); ?>
 <?php echo form_open("users/registration"); ?>
  <p>
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="con_password">Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="con_password" name="con_password" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="firstname">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="adress">Address</label>
  <input type="text" id="adress" name="adress" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
  </p>

 <?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div><!--registration-->
```

And fragment of **model**

```
public function add_user()
{
      $data=array(
        'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password')),
        'permissions'=>'Normal',
        'firstname'  =>$this->input->post('firstname'),
        'lastname'  =>$this->input->post('lastname'),
        'adress'  =>$this->input->post('adress')
      );
    $this->db->insert('users',$data);
}
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: When comparing to "false" (or "true") always use ===. Not sure if this is the answer, but try it (and always do it in the future). PHP has a very lose type conversion so use triple equals for comparing both value and type.

Comment: @Robbie codeigniter user guide says to use `==` with form validation

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Fair enough and thanks for commenting - I stand corrected. [Although I'll add, *unless a library or framework says otherwise*, then always use === for comparing to true or false.]

Comment: @Robbie when a test is failing, making it *more* strict will not help it pass.

Comment: Try adding `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` to `$this->index()` output to see what is actually failing.  Silly question, but does your input data really pass all your validation rules?

Comment: @Don'tPanic - that's not a safe statement. Think about `strpos` for starters - `if (strpos("xyz", "x") == false) { echo "x does not appear - taking you to the home page";}` which potentially could have been (but I accept isn't) the situation here. Lets say that `->run()`returned the number of errors (i.e. 0) then it would have failed as the OP described.

Comment: $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));  add this too in your controller.

Comment: Oh deary me! Please do not use `md5()` for password encryption.  This is not considered secure.